# WebRTC video and photo at same time

Tags: camera, webrtc

I'm working on an application that transmits video in low quality using webrtc. Periodically I want to send from same camera single frame in high resolution.

When I try to acquire another stream using `getUserMedia` I get same low quality one and when I try to pass some constraints to force higher resolution then then operation fails with *overconstrained* error (even though normally when there is no other stream it works fine).

Is it even possible to have at the same time many streams with different parameters from same device? Or is it possible acquire high resolution image without requesting for a new stream?

Comment: Seeing your code would be helpful.

Comment: @jib My code isn't fit for posting here. I was more interested about whether it is possible in principle.